# Compose function with data object method

Tags: scala

I am trying to compose a function with a data object's method.

I have a list that I want to map to another type (Id).

```
case class Href(val value: String) {
  def toId(): Id = {
    return null //null for clarity
  }
}

def toHref(element: WebElement): Href = {
    return Href(element.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

`seq.map(toHref _ andThen ((href:Href)=>href.toId))`

`toHref` just maps a `WebElement` to a `Href`. I would like to compose the function `toHref` with the member function `Href.toId`. Is there a shorter cleaner way to express this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines gives the desired results, but may not be what you're after in terms of composing the function and the method.

`seq.map(toHref(_).toId)`

Slightly shorter but equivalent to your version is:

`seq.map((toHref _) andThen (_.toId))`